# Remove text between last 2 slashes (PHP)

Tags: php

I have made a system with browsing files; Now I have a problem:

My path string like this: **`A/Abba/2004/`**

I want to remove the text between the last 2 slashes *(which is 2004 in this case)*.
So the output should look like **`A/Abba/`**

Can anyone help me as how to archive this in php?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to remove last part of string you can do this this way:

```
$input = 'A/Abba/2014/';
$array = array_filter(explode('/', $input));
array_pop($array);
$correct = implode('/', $array);
```

`array_filter` removes empty strings from array

`explode` converts string to array by given delimiter

`array_pop` remove last item from given array

`implode` converts array to string using given 'glue'

Comment: I corrected the answer, it 'll be reflected if piotr accepts it.

Comment: You are right, i've forgot about slash at the end. Thank you

Comment: I have made a mistake, but your answer is the best. Thanks it works.